# MemoryError when parsing XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am trying to find the specific tag in an XML file and I used `BeautifulSoup` to read the XML file. It produces the following error:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, 'xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-f431fabb5903>", line 1, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, 'xml')

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._feed()

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 448, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 203, in feed
    markup = StringIO(markup)

MemoryError
```

The size of the file is 353 MB but it has also parsed a larger file and did not produce this error. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: check if you have a 32 bit version of python or 64 bit

Comment: I have 64 bit version.

Comment: What is `XML`? We need more context here to help. Please see set up a [mcve].